# Problem with AutoFilter and Object/Application Defined Error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, runtime-error, autofilter

I am currently trying to filter two sets of data on two different sheets using the AutoFilter function in VBA. When I run the code, it deletes the contents on the page underneath some headers and copies data from another page to paste on both sheets. Then the sheets are suppose to autofilter based on a number that is user-inputted and sets that as the Top # of items we need to view. It gives me an object/application error (Error 1004) when it tries to set the range of the data in each page. What could the issue be?

```
Sub FilterTop10()
Dim Number As Integer, TopItems, TopPrice As Worksheet, Analyze As Worksheet
Dim data As Range, Prices, Items As Range

Set TopItems = Worksheets("Top Number by items")
Set TopPrice = Worksheets("Top Number by Price")

TopItems.AutoFilterMode = False
TopPrice.AutoFilterMode = False

TopItems.UsedRange.Offset(2, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 2).ClearContents
TopPrice.UsedRange.Offset(2, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 2).ClearContents

Set Analyze = Worksheets("Data to be Analyzed")
Set data = Analyze.Range("K3", Analyze.Range("N3").End(xlDown))

data.Copy TopItems.Range("A3")
data.Copy TopPrice.Range("A3")

Set Items = TopItems.Range("A2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
Set Prices = TopPrice.Range("A2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))

Number = InputBox("How many top items/prices do you want to see?")

Items.AutoFilter Field:=3, _
                        Criteria1:=Number, Operator:=xlTop10Items
                                    
Prices.AutoFilter Field:=4, _
                        Criteria1:=Number, Operator:=xlTop10Items
                                    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```vb
Set Items = TopItems.Range("A2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
Set Prices = TopPrice.Range("A2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
```

should be

```vb
Set Items = TopItems.Range("A2", TopItems.Range("D2").End(xlDown))
Set Prices = TopPrice.Range("A2", TopPrice.Range("D2").End(xlDown))
```

Without a worksheet qualifier, `Range()` (in a standard code module) will refer to the ActiveSheet, which may not be the sheet you want.

Also:

```
Dim data As Range, Prices, Items As Range
```

actually declares `Prices` as Varaint, not range.  In VBA each variable needs a type.

Comment: Ah, that did the trick! I guess I worked too quick and forgot to include the sheet on the second group of ranges. Thanks Tim!